# Condescending term for people that love to imagine/make up stuff, like astrophysicists

Tags: single-word-requests, terminology

I'm looking for a derogatory term for people or community of people that always make up theory that is unproven and so far fetched, but it's somehow accepted by most people as mainstream science.

To put it in context:

> Those astrophysicists telling me to believe in string theory, multiverse, parallel universe, loop quantum gravity, etc, but reject the flat earth theory?? What shills!

Comment: What's the reason for negative vote?

Comment: Is the mainstream science "string theory", gravity" and "quantum physics" or is it the "flat earth" belief? It's not clear who you are denigrating. The real astrophysicists or those who do not know what it means to be a scientist?

Comment: It is unwise to be derogatory of complicated theories (like string theory) which are difficult to grasp, let alone prove or disprove. I would simply refer to propagators of such theories as 'theorists' and leave the subject open. All of the subjects you mention (apart from flat earth) are impossible to prove or disprove.

Comment: A shill is someone who works for or speaks on behalf of someone else while pretending not to, so not sure it is really appropriate here. https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/shill

Answer (score 1):

People who propose their own "personal theories" (flat earth, etc) can be described as [pseudoscientists](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pseudoscience) or [crackpots](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/crackpot).

There is also the related term, [cargo cult science](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cargo_cult_science).

Answer (score 0):

They have [vivid imaginations](https://www.macmillandictionary.com/us/dictionary/american/a-vivid-imagination), often accompanied by considerable education and intelligence!

> if you have a vivid imagination, you are able to imagine ideas,
>   images, etc. very[!] easily

Comment: "Vivid imagination" makes it seem like the theories are not accepted by mainstream science.

Comment: @Laurel my probably poor attempt to offer OP a description that would give leeway ... as all but flat earth are accepted, some more than others. Q entangle is a good example ... it took v imag.  will delete if you -1